# How to update a list of dictionaries from a user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and working on a task where I need to update a list of dictionaries from a customer input.

I have a list as follows:

```
drinks_info = [{'Pepsi': 2.0}, {'Coke': 2.0}, {'Solo': 2.50}, {'Mt Dew': 3.0}]
```

If the user inputs: Pepsi: 3.0, Sprite: 2.50

Then the list should update to: `[{'Pepsi': 3.0}, {'Coke': 2.0}, {'Solo': 2.50}, {'Mt Dew': 3.0}], {'Sprite': 2.50}`]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: any particular reason why is a list of dictionaries with a singular key and not a single dictionary with multiple keys ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. We can use a function to update list based on user inputs. This function would ask user for each list item separately.

```py
def update_drinks_info(drinks_info):
    for drink in drinks_info:
        for key, value in drink.items():
            print(key, value)
            new_price = input("Enter new price for " + key + ": ")
            if new_price != "":
                drink[key] = float(new_price)

    return drinks_info
```

This function asks user to enter the new price for the specified item, if user presses Enter, then the price stays same without any additional input.

2. We can use a function to update list based on user specified keys and values.

```py
def update_drinks_info(drinks_info, drink, price):
    index = None
    for i in range(len(drinks_info)):
        if drink in drinks_info[i]:
            index = i

    if index is None:
        drinks_info.append({drink: price})
    else:
        drinks_info[index] = {drink: price}

    return drinks_info

def split_input(input):
    drinks = input.split(", ")
    for drink in drinks:
        drink = drink.split(":")
        drink[1] = float(drink[1])
        update_drinks_info(drinks_info, drink[0], drink[1])
```

Using `split_input` function, we are dividing user input to separate arrays and update the drinks info using the specified `drink` and `price`.

For example:

```py
split_input(input("Enter drink and price: "))
```

with the example input of `Pepsi: 3.0, Sprite: 2.50` is going to update the price of both items.

Comment: The update_drinks_info and split_input function came close to what I wanted. Just a small issue is that when I run the split_input function and input a new drink  i.e 'Sprite: 2.0', this replaced the Pepsi information and the updated list returns: [{'Sprite': 2.0}, {'Coke': 3.0}, {'Solo': 2.5}, {'Mt Dew': 3.0}].

Comment: @Thomas.L I updated the second solution, please try again.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
def update_drinks(drinks_info, query_string):
    query_list = query_string.split(":")
    updated = False
    for drink_items in drinks_info:
        for values in drink_items.keys():
            if values == query_list[0].strip():
                updated = True
                drink_items[query_list[0].strip()] = float(query_list[1].strip())

    if not updated:
        drinks_info.append({query_list[0].strip(): float(query_list[1].strip())})



if __name__ =="__main__":
    drinks_info = [{'Pepsi': 2.0}, {'Coke': 2.0}, {'Solo': 2.50}, {'Mt Dew': 3.0}]
    for _ in range(2):
        query_string =input()
    # the string is given in the format DrinkName : Value
        update_drinks(drinks_info, query_string)

    print("The updated drink list")
    print(drinks_info)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. This may be easily implemented if transformed into a dictionary format;
2. And then get the user updates also in dictionary format;
3. Then update the drinks dictionary as was transformed;
4. Finally convert it back to the original list format

```
drinks_info = [{'Pepsi': 2.0}, {'Coke': 2.0}, {'Solo': 2.50}, {'Mt Dew': 3.0}]
drinks_info_dict = {item: value for drink in drinks_info for item, value in drink.items()}

user_input = "Pepsi: 3.0, Sprite: 2.50"
updates = {details.split(":")[0].strip(): float(details.split(":")[1]) for details in user_input.split(",")}

drinks_info_dict.update(updates)

drinks_info = [{item: value} for item, value in drinks_info_dict.items()]
print(drinks_info)
```

Output:

```
[{'Pepsi': 3.0}, {'Coke': 2.0}, {'Solo': 2.5}, {'Mt Dew': 3.0}, {'Sprite': 2.5}]
```